# Facebook Marketing API - Create ad without business page

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

is it possible to create an ad via the Facebook Marketing API without having or using a Facebook business page?
I hadn't found any reference that confirms this guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a link ad that is not connected to a page using an adcreative with fields title, body, object_url, and image_file or image_hash. For actor_id use your FB user ID which you can get from reading the /me endpoint.

More info on adcreatives is at  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adcreative/v2.4

Here's the curl example from that page.

```
-F 'object_url=https://www.link.com' \
-F 'title=my title' \
-F 'body=my ad body' \
-F 'image_hash=<IMAGE_HASH>' \
-F 'actor_id=<ACTOR_ID>' \
-F 'access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/adcreatives
```